# Android Studio web view error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, android-webview-javascript

I have a web view application in Android Studio. The application works normally on the computer, namely chrome. But I get the following error in web view. What could be the problem? Thanks.

```
$.post( "https://xxxxxx",
          {
            car_id:carid
          },
      (Error)----->    ).done(function(data) {   
              if(data=='0')
              {
```

Android Studio Error:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(318)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected
> token )", source: xxxxx (318)

UPDATE:

I found the problem. It was giving an error because of the comma in the top line. But I still want to know the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some paranthesis problem. You probably forgot to close one.